# Android - LinearLayout Border

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a border to my page, but i failed to do that..
my code is

```
@drawable/custom_border

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="0dp"/> 
<padding android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/Black"/>
</shape>
```

My problem is the that, the Black color is setting to whole view(as a background), i want a border of black color not a background of black color.
What I am failing to do??
Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `solid` attribute is the background color. You should try to set it to

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

To set the color of the border :

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/Black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is change `<solid>` to `<stroke>`. So try changing

```
<solid android:color="@color/Black"/>
```

to

```
<stroke android:color="@color/Black"/>
```

`<solid> is a fill where`` will be used as your border.